# Benchmarking mlr3 - build models that differ in included predictors?

Tags: benchmarking, xgboost, mlr3

I have data where the predictors have some natural grouping (some are questionnaire scores, some are biological variables). Is there any way to use the benchmarking in mlr3 to compare models based on this? I have tried to set it up, but it doesn't work - potentially because I have defined as 'tasks' what should better be somehow captured as learners? (this is using xgboost)

```
reg.tasks=list()
reg.tasks$everything = as_task_classif(df,target='Reiteration',id='everything')
reg.tasks$biological = as_task_classif(df %>% dplyr::select(any_of(biological.vars)),target='Reiteration',id='everything')

future::plan(list('multisession'))
at=auto_tuner(method=tnr('random_search'),
              learner=lts(lrn('classif.xgboost')),
              resampling=rsmp('cv',folds=4),
              measures=msr('classif.bacc'),
              term_time=1*60))) # just to test
outer_resampling=rsmp('cv',folds=3)

bm_design=data.table::data.table(
  task=c(reg.tasks$everything,reg.tasks$everything,reg.tasks$biological), 
  learner=list(at,lrn('classif.featureless'),at),
  resampling=list(outer_reampling,outer_resampling,outer_resampling)
bmr=bechnmark(bm_design,store_models=TRUE)

bma=as.BenchmarkAggr(brr,measures=msr('classif.bacc'))
bma$friedman_posthoc()
```

I get an error for the postdoc tests

```
Warning: only two learners available, returning global test. Error in friedman.test.dfault(mf[[1L]],mf[[2L]],mf[[[3L]]: not an unreplicated complete block design
```

Comment: The friedman test as implemented in `mlr3benchmark` requires a full task x learner table, which you don't have. Why did you not include the featureless learner on the biological data?

Comment: I assumed that the feature less learner would mean not using any of the features from either the biological or the 'everything' etc. data? The values to be predicted are exactly the same for all data sets. So I assumed the featureless would be every time the same?

Comment: Yes I understand that this is the reason why you left it out. But if you want to use the friemdan test as implemented via mlr3benchmark, you need to ensure that a full task x learner result matrix is available.